# Does power steering fluid go bad quickly?

Tags: power-steering, safety, brake-fluid, fluid, power-steering-fluid

I've always heard that brake fluid goes bad real fast (IIRC, it absorbs the moisture in the air).

What about power steering fluid?

Can you buy a large container and use it over the years?  Or, like brake fluid, should you only buy what you need for one use?

Comment: How large is large @RockPaperLizard? Power steering systems don't need much.

Comment: @GdD I'm thinking either a gallon or a quart.

Comment: A quart is a sensible amount for a car owner to keep on hand, a gallon not so much @RockPaperLizard. Unless you have a leak or flush the system it will take years to use a quart.

Answer (score 2):

Power steering fluid can be stored for several years in a sealed container. However the standards for power steering fluid vary by manufacturer and model year. The vehicle you are driving 5 years from now may not use the same fluid.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not as hygroscopic as brake fluid.

However, it can degrade over time - especially if the level is low and it gets overheated, It tends to go brown.

Normally the fluid will only need topping up if there is a leak - I still have a small (1 litre) container I carry in my car due to a previous leak which has been fixed.